# Do I need to write the `const` keyword when passing a `const_iterator` as argument?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, arguments, constants

```
static void MyClassMethod(
          std::list<AClass>                 & AnObject,
    const std::list<AClass>::const_iterator & BeginningPoint);
```

In my code, I'm passing a `const_iterator` of a `const` STL object. It feels like one of the constantnesses is redundant.

How does it differ if I only remove the `const` keyword, or if I only change `const_iterator` to `iterator`?

Comment: Better: pass a `const_iterator` by value: `static void MyClassMethod(
          std::list<AClass>                 & AnObject, std::list<AClass>::const_iterator BeginningPoint);`

Comment: If BeginningPoint is from AnObject, I would pass as not const_iterator, to be consistent with your non-const data structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::list<AClass>::iterator&
```

You can change the value through the iterator and you can change what the iterator points to outside the function.

```
std::list<AClass>::const_iterator&
```

You can't change the value through the iterator but you can change what the iterator points to outside the function.

```
const std::list<AClass>::iterator&
```

You can change the value through the iterator but you can't change what the iterator points to outside the function.

```
const std::list<AClass>::const_iterator&
```

You can't change the value through the iterator and you can't change what the iterator points to outside the function.

Take note that the iterators are passed by reference. If they were passed by value, the first const wouldn't matter so much. This is because changing the position of the iterator would only effect your local copy.

Comment: ... raises the question, why are the iterators passed by reference anyway, if it isn't desired to return a new, modified iterator to the caller.

Comment: @BenVoigt The obvious answer could be "To guarantee 100% that no unnecessary copy will be made", why isn't that a valid point in your opinion?

Comment: @Antonio: I don't think an object would qualify as an iterator if it has non-trivial cost of copying.  All the standard algorithms make copies of iterators.  Also, you're not avoiding making a copy of the iterator, since you'll need to make a copy in order to actually use it to iterate.  If you're not iterating, then why pass an iterator?

Comment: @BenVoigt You might use it to insert into a map for example, and to be pedantic, the end iterator does not iterate. Why does an interator require trivial cost of copying?

Comment: @Neil: You're right that the end iterator won't be modified.  Yet *every single standard algorithm passes it by value*.  One possible reason is that the algorithms are expected to be inlined, and any extra copy will be elided.  I don't see how providing a `const` iterator helps with insertion into a map, either the key is already present and a reference to the value is good enough, or the key isn't present and therefore you can't form an iterator to it, or you're providing a hint which may be in the wrong place, and therefore iteration may be needed after all.

Comment: @BenVoigt In C++ isn't the usual practice to pass by const& in case the object is costly to copy, and the function will make a copy if it needs to modify it? In that case, the standard algorithms seem to be an anomaly.

Comment: @NeilKirk: `const&` actually hurts performance, possibly A LOT (indirection, and the possibility of aliasing kills many optimizations), for small cheap-to-copy objects.  Which iterators are expected to be.  So no, the correct practice is to pass by `const&` only if you have reason to believe the object is costly to copy.  I wouldn't worry about what practice is "usual", there are an awful lot of awful programmers out there.

Comment: @BenVoigt I consider it a weakness in the language, especially for templates, there is not a special way to mark [by value for small, by const ref for big]. For example, I made some numeric template functions only using basic types by value. Then I needed to use a costly arbitrary precision integer class in some cases. So I had to change to const ref, and rely the compiler will optimize for the basic data type.

Comment: @Neil: Actually the language is perfectly capable of doing that, it's just that the Standard library doesn't include a pre-built version.   But the low-level type traits needed to make one are there.

Comment: @BenVoigt Could you please explain how I can do this, as I would be very interested in using in my projects.

Comment: @Neil: Remind me in a couple hours, I shouldn't even be spending time on SO right now.

Comment: @Neil: Actually you probably should simply ask as a question, there are plenty of experts here capable of doing so.  I would combine (1) a template class with a typedef, which automatically chooses a reference or not based on the built-in type trait `is_trivially_copyable` (2) specializations when the automatic choice doesn't work (3) a template-typedef alias to make using it more convenient.

Answer (score 7):

A `const_iterator` means you can't modify the object it "points" to (iterators have pointer semantics). A `const` `const_iterator` means you can't modify the iterator itself.

So:

```
 const std::list<AClass>::const_iterator it = smth;
 it = smthElse;
```

is illegeal, and

```
 std::list<AClass>::const_iterator it = smth;
 it->nonConstMethodOfAClass();
```

is illegal.